# What is the correct name for this multiplicand

Tags: terminology, finance

We are providing a loan for 1 year and wish to tell the customer how much they will pay us per month, taking into account that they will pay `15%` up front as a deposit and make `11` monthly payments on the loan (the remaining `85%`).

So we multiply the total by `0.15` to get the deposit (`15%`) - so `£150` up front.

And then (taking account of an APR of `27.1%`), to calculate the instalment amount for 11 months, we have been told to take the total price of the product that we are offering, e.g. `£1,000` and multiply it by this "magic value" `0.08693`, so `£1,000*0.08693=£86.93`.

This gives us `(£86.93 * 11) + £150 = £1,106.23` total amount repayable, so `£106.23` in interest over the year.

In the domain of financing loans, what is the correct name for this magic multiplicand (`0.08693`)? It seems to serve a few purposes all at once:

1. It takes care of adding the relevant amount of interest to the loan, whilst simultaneously taking into account the fact that the customer is financing `85%` of the loan
2. It works out how much the customer would need to pay per month given that there will be 11 payments.

I care from a mostly theoretical perspective as we have modelled this in code and I want to name the constant with an appropriate name.

Comment: Hey, what is the interest rate? $i=...?$

Comment: Wouldn't it be `10.623`%? So, `£1,000*0.10623=£106.23`

Comment: Actually sorry, I think it'd be something like: £1,000 (total)-£150(deposit)=£850 loan
(monthly instalment)£86.93*11 (months)=£956.23 (total repayable)
£106.23 of interest on an £850 loan=12.497647058823529%